# What is the 'transaction' command in Firebase-Unity Plugin?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transactions, firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase-Unity plugin. (https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-12-18-firebase-unity.html)

Does anybody know what is the transaction command in this plugin?
Is it implemented in the plugin? If yes, can I see the sample code?

Comment: Can we see your code first? What have you tired?

Comment: I don't have the code. This is not the error case but I'd like to make a firebase transaction code in my future Unity project. The matter is there's no manual for the Firebase-Unity plugin and I'm curious if the 'transaction' can be done or not with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase-Unity plugin does not expose the complete underlying SDK functionality. The `transaction()` method of the Firebase SDK is one of the methods that is not exposed.

The author of the plugin recently commented somewhere on how to add such methods yourself. I'll see if I can find that link for you.

Comment: Oh, it's not implemented yet. Thanks. I was looking forward to seeing that kind of comments.

Answer (score -1):

The tutorial that you've linked, https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-12-18-firebase-unity.html is a good tutorial if not missing some steps.

Try this library out while following the tutorial above from Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity

Does that help?

Comment: I am confused. The link is not the tutorial but announcement about releasing new plugin. And github link is a kind of simple tutorial with some good example, however, it's not saying about 'transaction' command. I made some games with Firebase-Unity plugin before, and I succeeded in reading and writing data with Firebase. The matter is that it doesn't guarantee safe reading & writing among many people simultaneously because there's no transaction command inside. It's just reading and writing sequentially without protecting DB during the process.